# Passing additional data to the intermediate table using sync() in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I've got the following, which works as expected:

`$aircraft->logbook_entries()->sync($request['tasks']);`

I want to add "work_order_id" to my pivot table, so I've done the following:

- Added `->withPivot('work_order_id')` to the `Aircraft` and `Task` models in the appropriate `belongsToMany` relationships
- Updated my query to read `$aircraft->logbook_entries()->sync([1 => ['work_order_id' => $workorder->id], $request['tasks']]);`

This does not add the `work_order_id` to the pivot table as desired. Instead I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (pams_amo.airframe_logbook_entries, CONSTRAINT airframe_logbook_entries_work_order_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (work_order_id) REFERENCES work_orders (id)) (SQL: insert into airframe_logbook_entries (aircraft_id, created_at, task_id, updated_at) values (1, 2019-03-04 22:11:48, 12, 2019-03-04 22:11:48))

I followed the Laravel 5.1 Documents: [Many To Many Relationships - syncing for convenience](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) that says:

> Syncing For Convenience
>
> You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the array will exist in the intermediate table:
>
> $user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
>
> You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:
>
> $user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how the sync method works if you want to pass an additional column. All you have to do is to call the sync method as:

```
$tasks = array_combine(
    $request['tasks'],
    array_fill(0, count($request['tasks']), ['work_order_id' => $workorder->id])
);

$aircraft->logbook_entries()->sync($tasks);
```

So, the idea is that if you want to pass an additional parameter to the pivot, the task ID becomes the array key and the additional parameter is sent as the array value

Comment: I'm confused, because the docs mention that you can add an additional column, but all it refers to is this `sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3])` bit of code...why wouldn't it mention that other step?

Comment: Which step? Their example is not very relevant probably because the `expires` column on the pivot has a default value of `false`. So they skipped adding the column to the `2` and `3` IDs as the column will be automatically set by the db. In your case you must add the column to all the tasks IDs in order to be saved for all of them

Comment: I meant the extra step you have, where you add it to the array. Anyways, I used your code and it works great, thanks very much!